Code-Fold Only Select Blocks using Quarto
I'd like to prompt Quarto (HTML output) to fold some code blocks but not others with the initial output. So far, I've been able to get all code blocks to fold using code-fold: true.
Is there a way to prompt select code blocks to fold and others to not with this global setting?
---
  title: "Example"
  format: html
  editor: visual
  markdown: 
  editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
  code-fold: true
  code-summary: "Show the code"
---

```{r}
# Block to fold initially

```{r}
# Block to keep unfolded initially (override the global settings)


You can use an R object in conjunction with !expr to do this. See here for details.

To fold a block:  ```{.fold}
This block will be folded
print("Hello, World!")

You can add it as an argument to the code chunk like:  ```{r} #| code-fold: true [...] ```  and this code block/chunk will be folded.
